# Observer not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, console, migration

I have an observer who creates some records (tickets) when the status of a record (bookings) changes. It works ok when running the application. But wont run during migrations or in the rails console. And for I can understand, it should

This is in application.rb

```
# Activate observers that should always be running.
config.active_record.observers = :booking_observer
```

heres's the observer (booking_observer.rb)

## coding: utf-8

```
class BookingObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  require 'logger'

  def create_ticket(booking, passenger, leg)
    ticket = Ticket.factory(booking, passenger, leg)
    begin
      ticket.save!
    rescue Exception => e
      booking.logger.error "Can't save #{leg} ticket: #{e}"
    end
  end

  def after_update(booking)
    if booking.changed? && booking.changed_attributes()["status"]!=Booking::CONFIRMED && booking.status==Booking::CONFIRMED.to_sym
      passengers = booking.passengers.all
      passengers.each do |passenger|
        booking.logger.error "Passenger: #{passenger}"
        create_ticket(booking, passenger, Booking::DEPARTURE_LEG)
        create_ticket(booking, passenger, Booking::RETURN_LEG) if booking.booking_type.to_sym != :ow
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's a sample migration

```
class CreateTicketsForValidBookings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    bookings = Booking.where("departure_date < ?", 1.minute.ago).where(status: "confirmed")
    bookings.each do |booking|
      booking.status="migrating"
      booking.save
      booking.status="confirmed"
      booking.save
    end
  end

  def down
    bookings = Booking.where("departure_date < ?", 1.minute.ago).where(status: "migrating")
    bookings.each do |booking|
      booking.status="confirmed"
      booking.save
    end
  end
end
```

In every single post I found, the people was trying to disable the observers. Well, in my case it's backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out you have to enable the observer in a per enviroment basis. These three files

```
config/enviroments/development.rb
config/enviroments/test.rb
config/enviroments/production.rb
```

Must activate observers that should always be running with.

```
config.active_record.observers = :booking_observer
```